# shell scripting: error handling in piped command

Tags: ksh

I have a set of commands chained with pipes like this:

```
cat very_big_data.csv | awk -f ../bin/repair_preproc.awk |  tr -d "\n" | tr "\007" "\n" | sed 's/>  *</></g' > output.csv
```

The CSV file to be processen is quite big (10-20GB), so I would like to keep it in one stream.

I yould need to be able to catch errors potentially raising in the chained commands, for example I would need to be sure if the awk, the tr and the sed commands finished ALL successfully.

Comment: Change your awk script so it will take care of your other requirements. Result: `awk -f repair2.awk very_big_data.csv > output.csv`. No chaining issues.

Comment: @WalterA unfortunately it is not an option. My lines are longer than the max record size in the awk implementation I use.

Comment: When you can't install `gawk` you might want to save the result in between. Try to write the tempfile on another partition/drive than your input and outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, finally I've found some answer.

In bash, there is az array, called PIPESTATUS, so you can check the exit status of every pipe member.

But I need to do it in AIX, I only have ksh. In ksh there is a shell option: pipefail. You can use this to get the first nonzero exit status from a pipe stricture. Well, in default AIX ksh it isn't working either, so you have to use ksh93 shell.

There it is.